# Using jena for creating RDF from XMl file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rdf, semantic-web, jena

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create RDF from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385143/create-rdf-from-xml)

I am sorry for asking this question for the second time, I am still still having problem in generating rdf from the following xml file.

```
<xml>
<person>
<name>Joe</name>
<website url="www.example1.com">contact1</website >
<vote>20</vote>
</person>
<person>
 <name>Anna</name>
<website url="www.example2.com">contact2</website>
 <vote>80</vote>
 </person>
 </xml>
```

I think using jena might solve the issue , but I am not sure how to do so, since each  has got three properties  and I would like the out put to look like the following

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/xml">
 <j.0:hasCritic>Joe</j.0:hasCritic>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=Joe >
 <j.0:haswebsite>"www.example1.com"</j.0:haswebsite>
  <j.0:hascontact>contact1</j.0:hascontact>
  <j.0:hasvote>80</j.0:hasvote>
 </rdf:Description>
<j.0:hasCritic>Anna</j.0:hasCritic>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about=Anna>
 <j.0:haswebsite>"www.example2.com"</j.0:haswebsite>
  <j.0:hascontact>contact2</j.0:hascontact>
  <j.0:hasvote>20</j.0:hasvote>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5):

You can't parse the XML with Jena, unless it is RDF/XML.

You'll have to use XLST to transform the XML to RDF or parse the XML with a Java XML library to get the data and create the triples from the data of interest.

Using XSLT is fairly simple, as demonstrated from the example below.

Since the website is URL I'd use it as a URI rather than a literal. Also, FOAF is common for names. So, I'd use something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
            xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/"
            xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo#">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <rdf:RDF>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
<xsl:variable name="critic"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="criticWebsite"><xsl:value-of select="website/@url"/</xsl:variable>
<foo:hasCritic>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/critic/{$critic}">
        <foaf:name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></foaf:name>
        <foaf:homepage>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://{$criticWebsite}">
                <rdfs:label><xsl:value-of select="website"/></rdfs:label>
            </rdf:Description>
        </foaf:homepage>
    </rdf:Description>
</foo:hasCritic>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/"
    xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo#">

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/xml">
        <foo:hasCritic>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/critic/Joe">
                <foaf:name>Joe</foaf:name>
                <foaf:homepage>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example1.com">
                        <rdfs:label>contact1</rdfs:label>
                    </rdf:Description>
                </foaf:homepage>
            </rdf:Description>
        </foo:hasCritic>
        <foo:hasCritic>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/critic/Anna">
            <foaf:name>Anna</foaf:name>
                <foaf:homepage>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example2.com">
                        <rdfs:label>contact2</rdfs:label>
                    </rdf:Description>
                </foaf:homepage>
            </rdf:Description>
        </foo:hasCritic>
        </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

You can then load the RDF file into Jena

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I really need to use jena instead of XSLT

Comment: Jena isn't an XML parser.  It can parse *RDF* XML, but that's a different thing.  You don't need to use Jena to parse and transform the XML, if you've been told that, that's misinformed.  Use Jena to process the resulting RDF.  The only thing close to using Jena to handle this is using their GRDDL support, but that's just using Jena to run XSLT against XML to turn it into RDF.

Comment: As it has already been pointed out, you can't parse the XML with Jena. You'll have to use XLST or parse the XML with a Java XML library to get the data and create the triples from the data of interest. I'll update my answer to underline this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using XSLT to convert that XML into RDF.  Since it is probably very regular, the XSLT will be quite straightforward to write and apply to get the RDF you want.  Then you can use Jena to parse the resulting RDF and do something with that.

Comment: I agree. I'd use XSLT to transorm XML like this to RDF.