# XML to RDF : using JENA GRDDL

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena

I want to transform xml files to RDF.
I think that JENA GRDDL can be used ,but I don't know how it works ! and I did not found any examples !
can you help me please to start using this API or show me any possible solutions !

Answer (score 2):

You can transform XML files to RDF using XSLT, typically targeting RDF/XML (see, e.g., [Using jena for creating RDF from XMl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499281/using-jena-for-creating-rdf-from-xml-file)). Jena can then read the resulting file.

You can even streamline this process and parse the result of the XSLT transformation directly using a `SAXResult` and [`SAX2Model`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/arp_sax.html).

GRDDL (see [the excellent primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/grddl-primer/)) standardises this procedure. It provides a way to discover an XSLT transformation for a given XML document: either directly using `grddl:transformation`, or indirectly for a class of documents using xml namespace schemas or html profiles. (see the [GRDDL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/grddl/) for the  details)

So GRDDL doesn't really help you as such: you still need to write the transformation for your files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!?
if I still have to write my transformations ! what is the benifit of using GRDDL !
 but is their any generic XSLT transformation that can do that ? because my xml files have differents schemas !

Comment: GRDDL is useful for data consumers, and producers using standard formats. There are tools such as [gloze](http://code.google.com/p/gloze/) which will turn any XML into RDF, but that's a encoding of the xml tree in and RDF graph. This may not be what you want either.

Comment: what I want to do is convert XML files described using different standards (ISO 19115, Dublin Core , Darwin Core...), those files is about geo metadata,collected from different web services ( via WPS). what I want to do is to convert those files to RDF so I can add them to a jena ontological model.