# GRDDL package in Jena Apache new version

Tags: xml, rdf

I would like to convert XML files to RDF, 
which point to XSLT stylesheet with the GRDDL reader in Jena.
However, I can't find the GRDDL package in latest Jena Javadoc.
For example com.hp.hpl.jena.grddl.impl.GRDDL.
Anyone could explain about this?
Thanks in advance.

Azizah

Comment: This question would be better asked on the jena mailing list - users@jena.apache.org - see https://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html for instructions on subscribing to the list

Comment: Have you seen [XML to RDF: using JENA GRDDL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15808478/1281433)?  I don't know if you'll find an answer there, but it's got some links to some other resources, anyhow.